# Powershell Set-AzureDeployment fails with a StorageException

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, deployment

I use the powershell script "PublishCloudService.ps1" from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/ to deploy my cloud projects. 
Somehow, one project doesn't deploy and I get the following error message:

```
Set-AzureDeployment : Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
At D:\Users\4711\Untitled1.ps1:78 char:22
+     $setdeployment = Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot $slot -Package $packageL ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureDeployment], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.SetAzureDeploymentCommand
```

The affected command is:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot $slot -Package $packageLocation -Configuration $cloudConfigLocation -label $deploymentLabel -ServiceName $serviceName -Force
```

Deploying the project manual using the publish dialog in visual studio works without any problems.

I already tryed to recreate the project in visual studio and created a new storage account but still face the same error. The script works for my other cloud projects well.

How can I get more information about the error? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the correct SDK?

Comment: I updated to sdk 2.1 but still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a workaround for my problem. Uploading the package to the blob storage and use the url in the Set-AzureDeployment command works fine:

```
# If the target container does not already exist, create it. 
$containerState = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $containerName -ea 0
if ($containerState -eq $null)
{
    New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $containerName | out-null
}

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $packageLocation -Container $containerName -Blob $blob -Force| Out-Null

$script:packageLocation = (Get-AzureStorageBlob -blob $blobName -Container $containerName).ICloudBlob.uri.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: You have saved my life! Very much appreciated. It seems like this is broken!

Comment: Yes, the Azure upload seems like broken. But the workaround still works fine. Happy to help you.

Comment: Did you add the above code to the existing "PublishCloudService.ps1" script?

Comment: @Khash yes, I added the above code to fix that issue. But maybe you can try the new Azure SDK 2.2 (released yesterday). I hope they fixed that issue...

Comment: @jisaak, I'm not very familiar with PS Scripts, but couldn't find out how to add your code snippet to the existing script (PublishCloudService.ps1), for instance I couldn't find "$containerName" in the script to use it in "Get-AzureStorageContainer", could you please attach the whole script? Thanks

Comment: @jisaak, Thanks mate, It worked, I added the Container name and blob name manually.